# Elasticsearch: Cannot search using Kuromoji reading form filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kuromoji

I'm using Elasticsearch 0.90.1 with Kuromoji plugin 1.4.0.

```
$ curl localhost:9200
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Agent Zero",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.1",
    "snapshot_build" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.3"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I create a new index, using Kuromoji for my `default` analyzer:

```
$ curl -X PUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "kuromoji_rf": {
          "type": "kuromoji_readingform",
          "use_romaji": "false"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "kuromoji": {
          "type": "kuromoji_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "kuromoji",
          "filter": [
            "kuromoji_rf"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

result:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

The reading form token filter seems to be working fine (kanji is normalized to katakana):

```
$ curl localhost:9200/test/_analyze -d '東京'
```

result:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "トウキョウ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Index a document:

```
$ curl -X PUT localhost:9200/test/docs/1 -d '{
  "body": "これは関西国際空港です"
}'
```

result:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "docs",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1
}%
```

The indexed document matches a wildcard query:

```
$ curl 'localhost:9200/test/docs/_search?q=body:*'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 109,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "docs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "body": "これは関西国際空港です"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't match when I search using Japanese:

```
$ curl 'localhost:9200/test/docs/_search?q=body:空港'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 21,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}

$ curl 'localhost:9200/test/docs/_search?q=body:クウコウ'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 95,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}

$ curl 'localhost:9200/test/docs/_search?q=body:空'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 22,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I wondered if maybe the analyzer was not being used for the search query, but specifying the analyzer does not help:

```
$ curl 'localhost:9200/test/docs/_search?analyzer=default&q=body:空港'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 17,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

By the way, everything works fine if I disable the token filter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your URL(e.x. `localhost:9200/test/docs/_search?q=body:クウコウ`) is not URL encoded string.
I try following command, return results.
`"クウコウ" -> "%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A6"`

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/test/docs/_search?q=body:%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A6'
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.11506981,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "docs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.11506981,
        "_source": {
          "body": "これは関西国際空港です"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```